# Set Theory proof about finding a bijective function between $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}C_{i}$ and $Y\subseteq X$. Proof Verification 1-2, explanation point 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

$X=\bigcup_{i\in I}C_{i}$ is a partition of X, and $Y\subseteq X$ is a subset of X.

1. If $\forall i \in I$ $ $ $h_{i}: C_{i}\to C_{i}\cap Y$ is injective, than prove that the application $h:X\to Y$ defined by $h(x):= h_{i}$ for $x\in C_{i}$ is injective.

My answer: first we should notice that $C_{i}\cap Y$ is non empty $\forall i\in I$ otherwise if $\exists i^{*}\in I$ such that the intersection is empty than $h_{i^{*}}$ is not defined.
If $h(x_{1})=h(x_{2})$ and $x_{1},x_{2}\in C_{i}$, being $h_{i}$ injective we have $h_{i}(x_{1})=h_{i}(x_{2})$ implies $x_{1}=x_{2}$. Lets assume  $h_{i}(x_1)=h_{j}(x_2)$ $i\neq j$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$ the implication comes from the definition of $h_{i}$ and $C_{i}$. If that is true than we should have that $C_{i}\cap Y$ and $C_{j}\cap Y$
have common elements, but that implies $C_{i}\cap C_{j}$ is non empty, which is an absurd. It follows that our assumption $h_{i}(x_{1})=h_{i}(x_{2})$ $i\neq j$ cannot be true.

2. Moreover, prove $h$ is bijective $\Leftrightarrow$ every $h_{i}$ is bijective.

My answer:
Lets prove $h_{i}$ bijective $\forall i\in I$ than $h$ is bijective. Being $h_{i}$ surjective $\forall i\in I$ than $\bigcup_{i\in I}h_{i}(C_{i})=Y$.
$h_{i}$ is also injective $\forall i\in I$ so $\forall x_{1},x_{2}\in C_{i}$ with $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$ we have $h_{i}(x_{1})\neq h_{i}(x_{2})$.
Lets prove the inverse relation.
$h$ injective than $\forall x_{1},x_{2}\in X$ so that $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$ we have $h(x_{1})\neq h(x_{2})$ which implies $h_{i}(x_{1})\neq h_{j}(x_{2}) \forall i,j \in I$
$h$ surjective than $\forall y\in Y \exists x\in X$ such that $h(x)=h_{i}(x)=y$ If $h_{i}$ weren't surjective than $\exists y^{*}\in C_{i}\cap Y$ such that $y\notin h_{i}(C_{i})$ wich is an absurd.

3. In particular, if $\forall i\in I$  $h_{i}:C_{i}\to C_{i}\cap Y$ is bijective than prove it exists a bijection $h: X \to Y$.

My answer: Actually i don't understand what i have been request to do. I have to find a specific bijective function? May it help that: For the injectivity: $h_{i}(C_{i})\cap h_{j}(C_{j})$ is empty $\forall i,j \in I$ and $i \neq j$. For the surjectivity:  $h_{i}(C_{i})$ is non empty $\forall i \in I$, moreover $\bigcup_{i\in I}h_{i}(C_{i})=Y$ ?

Comment: I would appreciate why i got a downvote. Thanks

Comment: You’ve shown good effort. I think the downvote came because the title might make a reader think (at a glance) that this is a very low effort question of the style we see lots of, every day. Maybe also clarify at the start you want verification for points $1,2$ but help for point $3$.

Comment: Changing "help" to "clarification" is not really an improvement. You have 150 characters, you can use MathJax, those are you limitations. Describe your actual question. While you're editing that, your definition of $h$ in (1) should be $h(1):=h_i(x)$. And do you want us to explain a proof to you, or help you improve your proof? Your choice of tags seems at odds with itself.

Comment: In 1. you did not cover the case $x_1\in C_i, x_2\in C_j$ with $i\ne j$. It's an easy case..... BTW in 7 years I haven't seen anyone except myself who gave a non-anonymous down-vote, or an explanation.

Comment: I have, but it is admittedly very rare

Comment: Again, your title is telling us about *you* and not about *the content of your question*.

Comment: And please don't add tags that are irrelevant to the question back.

Comment: Now the title is ok? Any observation about proof 1-2 or any advice for point 3? Thanks @Asaf Karagila

Comment: I have made corrections. Any other observation? Can you help with point 3? @DanielWainfleet

Comment: (3) seems to be an immediate consequence of points (1) and (2). Point (1) proves the existence and injectivity of $h$, and point (2) proves that $h$ is bijective. That is all (3) requires. I think they are trying to point out that this particular fact is part of what you just proved.